# Retrieving multiple files(images) from storage in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, axios

I'm trying to retrieve files I upload to my local disk in storage/app/clients. I don't want to make it public. All the ways I see people retrieve multiple files are to put them in the public folder but I want to keep it to logged in users.

My controller for uploading files (formdata) :

PicturesController.php

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $images = $request->file();
    $client = $request->get("ClientID");
    $treatment = $request->get("TreatmentID");

    $path = 'clients\\' . $client . '\\' . $treatment . '\\';


    foreach ($images as $image) {

        //StorePicture
        $randomName = Str::random(8);
        $date = date("_d-m-Y_H-i-s.", time());
        $extension = $image->extension();
        $filename = $randomName.$date.$extension;
        $image->storeAs($path, $filename);

        //Save to database
        $picture = new Picture();
        $picture->picPath = $path.$filename;
        $picture->Treatment()->associate($treatment);

        $picture->save();
    }

}
```

This stores the file(s) without any problems.

I have looked everywhere I could but haven't found any solution to retrieve the pictures and pass them to the vue.js frontend.
Does anyone have a link where this is done or and idea?

So far :

```
public function show($id)
{
    //Collection of Picture (paths...)
    $picturesCollection= Picture::where('fkTreatment', $id)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();

    $images = array();

    foreach ($picturesCollection as $pic) {
        //Store images in an array to return it to ModalDisplay.vue
        $images[] = ?;
    }

    return $images;
}
```

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

TL:DR

picPath attribute should contain the actual file path

I am sharing you a snippet which I used to manage my files

```
    $auth_id = 0;
    $storage_details = [];

    if (auth()->check()) {
        $auth_id = auth()->user()->id;
    }

    $file_name = $auth_id . '_' . date('d-m-Y_H-i-s') . '.' . $file->getClientOriginalExtension();

    $store = $this->getStorage()->putFileAs('records', $file, $file_name);
    if (!$store) {
        return $storage_details;

    } else {

        $storage_details['file_path'] = $this->getStorage()->getDriver()->getAdapter()->getPathPrefix() . 'records' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $file_name;
        $storage_details['file_name'] = $file_name;
        $storage_details['driver'] = $this->getStorage()->getDriver();
        $storage_details['disk'] = $this->getDisk();
        $storage_details['relative_path'] = 'records' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $file_name;

        return $storage_details;
    }
```

And here is how I am saving them to DB

```
    $task = new self();
    $task->id = $task_id;
    $task->user_id = auth()->user()->id;
    $task->type = 'process_records';

    $meta = [];
    if (array_key_exists('file_path', $storage_details)) {
        $meta['file_path'] = $storage_details['file_path'];
    }
    if (array_key_exists('file_name', $storage_details)) {
        $meta['file_name'] = $storage_details['file_name'];
    }
    if (array_key_exists('driver', $storage_details)) {
        $meta['driver'] = $storage_details['driver'];
    }
    if (array_key_exists('disk', $storage_details)) {
        $meta['disk'] = $storage_details['disk'];
    }
    if (array_key_exists('relative_path', $storage_details)) {
        $meta['relative_path'] = $storage_details['relative_path'];
    }

    $task->meta = $meta;
    $task->save();
```

Now All you need is to iterate over the relative path and if in future you change your driver to AWS or something else you can easily implement logic